# Java Processbuilder GitLog pretty-format

Tags: java, git, processbuilder, git-log

I create a java method to make a gitlog from a git repo.

Method:

```
String gitLogFormat = "--pretty=format:\"%H %an %ad %s\"";

List<String> cmds = Arrays.asList("git", "log", gitLogFormat, "--numstat",  "--date=short");
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
builder.directory(new File( GitPath.toAbsolutePath().toString() ));

builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to( path.resolve("gitlog.txt").toFile() ) );

Process process = builder.start();
```

If i run this method without `gitLogFormat` it works and I get a file with the Gitlog. But with the format I always get the exitcode `128`.

Is there a Problem with the `\"` because the other both options `--numstat` and `--date=short` works?

**Update**

I try it with :

```
String gitLogFormat = "--pretty=format:\"%H_%an_%ad_%s\"";
```

and it works.

The Whitespaces are the Problems. Have anyone an idea how i can use the code with withespaces because the Log should have spaces between the informations.

Comment: The code works fine, I think the problem is unrelated to `gitLogFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2 and Solution:**

The Problem are the Whitespaces so i must add between every whitespace a `,`

It works with this code :

```
List<String> cmds = Arrays.asList("git", "log", "--pretty=format:\"%H" , "%an" , "%ad" , "%s\"" , "--numstat" , "--date=short");
```